# Count the number of combinations with gap-restriction for every pair of values

Tags: python, recursion, combinatorics

A lottery draw consists of choosing 6 different values from 1 to 50.

I want to calculate the number of combinations with gaps of at least 3 between every pair of values.

I have used the following Python 2.7 script:

```
def func(array,length,min,max,gap):
    if len(array) == length:
        # print array
        return 1
    count = 0
    for n in range(min,max+1):
        count += func(array+[n],length,n+gap,max,gap)
    return count;

print func([],6,1,50,3)
```

Questions:

- Are there any coding improvements that I can apply?
- Is there a different method with which we can do it more efficiently?
- Although more suitable for [math.stackexchange.com](http://math.stackexchange.com), is there a straightforward formula?

Comment: When I run your script, I get `TypeError: func() missing 2 required positional arguments`

Comment: @GarethRees: Sorry, I initially had `length` and `gap` hard-coded in the function. I changed them to be function arguments after I had already posted the question, but I forgot that the function itself was recursive (so the recursive call consisted of 3 instead of 5 parameters). Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. There's no docstring. How do I use this function? What arguments do I pass? What does it return?
2. It would be very easy to make this code portable to Python 3: just put parentheses around the argument to `print`.
3. There's no need to terminate a statement with a semicolon in Python.
4. The name `func` does not give any hint as to what the function might do. A name like `combinations_with_gap` would be clearer.
5. When you have code that accumulates a sum like this:

   ```
   count = 0
   for n in A:
       count += B
   ```

   you can use the built-in [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum):

   ```
   count = sum(B for n in A)
   ```
6. If you're just *counting* combinations (rather than generating the combinations themselves), then you don't need the `array` variable, just its length.
7. Presumably the caller is supposed to always pass the empty list `[]` for `array` and `1` for `min`. In that case, why make them do it? It would be easier for the caller if the function just took the arguments you need, and used a local function to do the work, like this:

   ```
   def combinations_with_gap(k, max, gap):
       """Return the number of ways of choosing k of the numbers from 1 to
       max such that no two numbers are closer than gap.

       """
       def c(length, min):
           if length == k:
               return 1
           return sum(c(length + 1, n + gap) for n in range(min, max + 1))
       return c(0, 1)
   ```
8. This runs in just over 4 seconds on my computer:

   ```
   >>> from timeit import timeit
   >>> timeit(lambda:combinations_with_gap(6, 50, 3), number=1)
   4.182408502034377
   ```

   Where is it spending its time? If you trace the calls to the inner function `c`, you'll see that the same values for `length` and `min` occur many times. This is a waste of effort: having computed `c(5, 44)`, say, it would be a good idea to remember the result and reuse it instead of computing it again.

   One way to do this is to [*memoize*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) the function, for example using the [`@functools.lru_cache`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache) decorator:

   ```
   from functools import lru_cache

   def combinations_with_gap(k, max, gap):
       """Return the number of ways of choosing k of the numbers from 1 to
       max such that no two numbers are closer than gap.

       """
       @lru_cache(maxsize=None)
       def c(length, min):
           if length == k:
               return 1
           return sum(c(length + 1, n + gap) for n in range(min, max + 1))
       return c(0, 1)
   ```

   This version takes just a couple of milliseconds:

   ```
   >>> timeit(lambda:combinations_with_gap(6, 50, 3), number=1)
   0.0017554410151205957
   ```

Comment: Thank you very much. 3. Ooops, I thought I had removed all of those semicolons (C habit). 5. I think that this would create a huge (temporary) array at some point, so I'm not sure it is such a good idea. 6. As implied by the `# print array`, I wanted to be able to easily generate those combinations. 8. So I guess that you're implying towards an iterative solution (a.k.a *dynamic programming*) instead of the recursive one?

Comment: 5. No array is created: `B for n in A` is a generator expression. 6. If you want fast counting of combinations, but also want to generate the combinations, then you need two different functions. 8. Yes: recursion plus memoization is a form of dynamic programming, but no: I don't suggest you use an iterative solution (recursion plus memoization is usually clearer).

Comment: Thank you, this is a very good answer (in particularly the last section)!

Answer (score 1):

Give your function a more descriptive name, `gapped_lottery` is not great but better than `func`.

Use an underscore after `min` and `max` to avoid shadowing built-ins.

Use a generator comprehension to shorten the code:

```
def gapped_lottery(array,length,min_,max_,gap):
    if len(array) == length:
        return 1
    return sum(gapped_lottery(array+[n],length,n+gap,max_,gap)
                  for n in range(min_, max_ + 1))
```

Omit the semicolon after `return;`

Comment: Thank you very much. 1. Did it with `length` (instead of `len`), but forgot about `min` and `max` being built-ins. 2. I think that the generator would create a huge (temporary) array at some point, so I'm not sure it is such a good idea. In any case, I think it makes it less readable. 3. Ooops, I thought I had removed all of those semicolons (C habit).

Comment: Can you explain what's wrong with shadowing built-ins here? The code does not use the built-in `min` or `max`, so what's the problem?

Comment: @barakmanos generators are lazy, they _generate_ the value as needed one by one, with no memory penalty. I think a generator is more readable but that depends on one's background.

Comment: @GarethRees in this case shadowing built-ins (that is: making it impossible to call native functions by naming something other as them) is a little problem, but I think that the habit of always avoiding them can avoid name conflicts at little cost.